# xcodebuild: Command failed with exit code 65 in Ionic Capacitor Application

Tags: ios, jenkins, ionic-framework, code-signing, capacitor

I have an ionic project and it uses a capacitor. The environment info for my project shows something like:

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.1.1 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework: ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.11

Capacitor:

   capacitor (Capacitor CLI) : 1.1.0
   @capacitor/core           : 1.1.0

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.0.0
   Cordova Platforms     : none
   Cordova Plugins       : no whitelisted plugins (0 plugins total)

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/Users/iosbuild/Library/Android/sdk)
   NodeJS            : v9.4.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm               : 6.4.1
   OS                : macOS High Sierra
   Xcode             : Xcode 9.4.1 Build version 9F2000



   ╭─────────────────────────────────────╮
   │                                     │
   │   Update available 4.1.1 → 5.2.3    │
   │    Run npm i -g ionic to update     │
   │                                     │
   ╰─────────────────────────────────────╯
```

To build & deploy the project, the project uses Fastlane. The Application is code-signed automatically.

The Gym of Fastlane looks like:

```
gym(
      scheme: IOS_SCHEME,
      workspace: IOS_WORKSPACE,
      export_method: EXPORT_METHOD[releaseType],
      export_xcargs: '-allowProvisioningUpdates',
      export_options: {
        'signingStyle': 'automatic',
        'compileBitcode': false
      }
    )
```

Suddenly, after a few months the build started failing with Error Code 65.
Here is the build failure message :

```
[33m▸[0m [39;1mProcessing[0m Info.plist
[33m▸[0m [39;1mGenerating 'App.app.dSYM'[0m
[33m▸[0m [39;1mRunning script[0m '[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks'
** ARCHIVE FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Embed\ Pods\ Frameworks /Users/iosbuild/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-fdavtmgcrorkxicfvghtsxxtwfeo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/App.build/Release-iphoneos/App.build/Script-9592DBEFFC6D2A0C8D5DEB22.sh
(1 failure)
[09:28:20]: [31mExit status: 65[0m

+---------------+-------------------------+
|            [32m[33mBuild environment[0m            |
+---------------+-------------------------+
| xcode_path    | /Applications/Xcode.app |
| gym_version   | 2.105.2                 |
| export_method | enterprise              |
| SDK           | iPhoneOS11.4.SDK        |
+---------------+-------------------------+

[09:28:20]: ▸ [35mtotal size is 10252820  speedup is 1.00[0m
[09:28:20]: ▸ [35mCode Signing /Users/iosbuild/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-fdavtmgcrorkxicfvghtsxxtwfeo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications//App.app/Frameworks/Capacitor.framework with Identity iPhone Developer: XXXX XXXX (XXXXXXXXX)[0m
[09:28:20]: ▸ [35m/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign <[Some alphanumeric text]>  --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements '/Users/iosbuild/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-fdavtmgcrorkxicfvghtsxxtwfeo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications//App.app/Frameworks/Capacitor.framework'[0m
[09:28:20]: ▸ [35m/Users/iosbuild/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-fdavtmgcrorkxicfvghtsxxtwfeo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications//App.app/Frameworks/Capacitor.framework: errSecInternalComponent[0m
[09:28:20]: ▸ [35mCommand /bin/sh failed with exit code 1[0m
```

After lots of googling, many solutions have been tried out, but Failure..!!
Following solutions are already tried:

- Keychain unlocks & lock.
- Check Valid Certificate & removing Expired Certificates.
- Set Keychain Password to Partition List.
- Reboot Mac.
- Duplicate Keychain Entries managing
- adding post_install to pod file. Disabling Code Signing for pods frameworks
- `pod install` using Fastlane.
- Cleared Derived data directory & Module folder.

Podfile looks like below:

```
platform :ios, '11.0'
use_frameworks!

# workaround to avoid Xcode 10 caching of Pods that requires
# Product -> Clean Build Folder after new Cordova plugins installed
# Requires CocoaPods 1.6 or newer
install! 'cocoapods', :disable_input_output_paths => true

def capacitor_pods
  # Automatic Capacitor Pod dependencies, do not delete
  pod 'Capacitor', :path => '../../node_modules/@capacitor/ios'
  pod 'CapacitorCordova', :path => '../../node_modules/@capacitor/ios'
  pod 'CordovaPluginsStatic', :path => '../capacitor-cordova-ios-plugins'
  # Do not delete
end

target 'App' do
  capacitor_pods
  # Add your Pods here
end
```

Cocoapods version for Mac-mini is, `1.7.4`

First Question here is, Does the Xcode version needs to be updated to 10?

SecondQuestion, Does the fastlane version matters? Current fastlane version used is : `2.105.2`

How can I solve this Archive Failed issue? The certificates required are all correctly installed. Trying this from days and still stuck here.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: On the machine where the archive step is being run, do you have _duplicate_ (albeit valid) signing certificates?

Comment: Try running `$ security find-identity -v -p codesigning` on the machine where the archive step is being run. If you see duplicate certificates (even if they're valid) the security API will fail this step silently because it can't tell which of the duplicate valid certs to use. This is just a hunch, though.

Comment: I'm pretty certain this is a code signing issue and probably not at all related to `fastlane`, `Xcode` or your choice of technologies.

Comment: @Aaron Thanks for reply. Yes, I've tried this command and it does not have any duplicated certificates and the certificates which I have, are Valid and not Expired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capacitor requires Xcode 10 or newer as latest version uses Swift 4.2, which is not available on Xcode 9

Comment: Thanks for answer. Yes, i have updated my Xcode to 10 and the project builds successfully.